# What are the restrictions on the use of "unless"?

Tags: syntax, english

I have found a restriction on the use of "unless" which was difficult to explain to my students (advanced ESL).

The student's sentence was

- I would have had to go to the bank unless you had lent me the money.

Several others produced similar sentences.
How can we explain the difference in acceptability between:

1. They'll kill her unless she gives them the money.
2. *They would have killed her unless she gave them the money.
3. They wouldn't have robbed her unless they were really poor.

Comment: This is a question about language usage, so it setter fits English.SE or EnglishLanguageLearners.SE

Comment: OK, I'll repost there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on EL&U